# Testing if a symbol is a hash-table in a macro

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I'd like to build a macro that expands to different forms depending on the type of the symbol supplied as an argument. A small reproducible example (two of them, actually... that fail on sbcl and ccl) is as follows:

```
λ (defmacro what-am-i (a-thing)
   (etypecase a-thing
        (list         `(format t "im a list"))
        (vector       `(format t "im a vector"))
        (hash-table   `(format t "im a hash-table"))))

λ (defmacro what-am-i2 (a-thing)
     (cond
        ((typep a-thing 'list)         `(format t "im a list"))
        ((typep a-thing 'vector)       `(format t "im a vector"))
        ((typep a-thing 'hash-table)   `(format t "im a hash-table"))))

λ (what-am-i '(1 2 3 4))
im a list
NIL

λ (what-am-i "abcd")
im a vector
NIL

λ (what-am-i *my-hash*)

debugger invoked on a SB-KERNEL:CASE-FAILURE in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10039846F3}>:
  *MY-HASH* fell through ETYPECASE expression.
  Wanted one of (LIST VECTOR HASH-TABLE).

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-KERNEL:CASE-FAILURE ETYPECASE *MY-HASH* (LIST VECTOR HASH-TABLE))
0] ^D

λ (what-am-i2 '(1 2 3 4))
im a list
NIL

λ (what-am-i2 "abcd")
im a vector
NIL

λ (what-am-i2 *my-hash*)

NIL
λ (typep *my-hash* 'hash-table)

T
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*type of the symbol* is always `symbol` :-)

The type of the symbol's *value* is not known until the code is *executed* (evaluated).

So, `(what-am-i '(1 2 3 4))` sees a list `(quote (1 2 3 4))` and reports that it is a list, while `(what-am-i *my-hash*)` sees a symbol `*my-hash*` and reports an error.

You can use `symbol-value` to access the global value of the symbol at macro-expansion time, but I suspect that you are asking the wrong question  here.

I suggest that you ask a separate question, explaining what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: This answer pretty much sums it up.  There *are* some types that you could detect at compile time (e.g., a literal list, or vector), sometimes people will write compiler macros that will expand to type specific forms.

Comment: I understand that approach on literals and constants, but not on variables.